# Wordpress adding image into post not working

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I have this problem whenever I insert image in a post, the image is not showing in the wordpress editor. I checked the console and there are no occuring errors.

[image: console]

Comment: That's the problem. When I add images in my post it doesn't show up in the editor. I dont have any plugins installed aside from akismet and this is a customize theme I'm making.

Comment: There is no clear problem for us to troubleshoot here.  if you cannot figure out what wordpress is doing behind the scenes, try reinstalling it or using a last-known-good back up.

Answer (score 0):

You have this in your code `src=""`, so the source of the image is empty. It should have the URL of the image, which you want. Insert the URL/path and you will see the image.

For example:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png">
```